# What is "2>" for in DOS / Windows console? (cmd.exe)

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, ms-dos

I've seen the following line in a .cmd file:

`ren fileA fileB 2> nul`

I know what ">nul" is for (to prevent any output from appearing), but what is "2> nul" for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two console output streams – stdout (1) and stderr (2). The former is supposed to be used for regular data output, while stderr is meant for warnings and error messages.

By default the `>` operator redirects only stdout; prefixing it with 2 will cause it redirect stderr instead. This lets you avoid accidentally mixing program warnings into data files.

(On Unix-like systems all redirection operators accept any fd number. Windows only borrowed the syntax but has a different underlying system, so it only deals with in/out/err.)

Comment: Now I understand, thanks. I forgot that using just ">nul" still actually showed errors (I guess they show through "stderr", as you explain, which I didn't know about). So using "2>nul" actually hides the error messages, which ">nul" didn't. BTW, excuse my ignorance but, what's an "fd number"?

Comment: An 'FD' is a [File Descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)...

Comment: When a program opens a file, on Windows it works with a "file handle"; on Unix-like systems it similarly gets a "file descriptor" (FD). The big difference is that Unix file descriptors are just numbered sequentially from 0, so they're directly exposed in the shell script (the same operator works with `1>`, `2>`, `3>`, `4>`...) Additionally things like the 'stderr' stream is file descriptor #2 only because that's the general convention, not because the kernel enforces it.